# Checkbox и обработка php

Tags: checkbox, php, html

Имеется checkbox, визуально он отключен (галочка снята), но html его таков:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type_edit[]" value="1" checked="checked">
```

Обработчик таков:

```
if($this->input->post('type_edit')) {
    foreach($this->input->post('type_edit') as $val){
        $data[] = $val;
    }
    var_dump($data); die(); // ничего не выводит

} // не заходит в это условие
```

Почему так?

Comment: Вы же сами написали, что не заходит в условие. Вот `var_dump()` ничего и не выводит.

Сделайте перед этим условием

    var_dump($this->input->post('type_edit'));

и покажите, что в нем

Answer (score 1):

> визуально он отключен (галочка снята)

Ну тогда в чем, собственно, вопрос? Поставьте галочку, чтобы получить `$_POST['type_edit']` не пустым (вернее чтобы вообще его получить)

Если checkbox не отмечен (checked), то в форме он не передается

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте следующий код:

```
$result = array();
foreach($_POST['type_edit'] as $data)
  $result[] = $data;
print_r($result);
```

если что-то выведет, значит проблема с

```
$this->input->post('type_edit')
```

Comment: Вывод null и ругается на foreach Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

зачем аттрибуту checked что-то присваивать. Попробуйте просто: 
`<input type="checkbox" name="type_edit[]" value="1" checked>`